# Adding multiple items from same drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have the  following drop down list populated from a db query. 
I am struggling to figure out a way to add items selected from this dropdownbox 
to essentially a list like a shopping cart which allows me  to make multiple additions from this drop down box. 
Can you anyone guide me with this

```
    <?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'blah', 'password');
mysql_select_db('reporting');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductNumber, Description FROM Stock WHERE ProductGroup ='800'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PRODS'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Description'] . "'>" . $row['Description'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: please clarify... you want a multiple select that allows a user to pick many options and send them into a shopping-cart? what part are you interested in, the _selecting_ or _populating the cart_? or both?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<select name='PRODS' multiple>";
```

With this you will be able to select multiple values form the select box.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'blah', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('reporting');

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductNumber, Description FROM Stock WHERE ProductGroup ='800'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name='PRODS' multiple>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Description'] . "'>" . $row['Description'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    ?>
```

Comment: ok thanks for that. i was just wondering about how i can place this now on another page or list . perhaps with jquery?